# Matlab : backtrack path from matrices

Tags: matlab, backtracking

I have a data :

```
minval =  NaN   7   8   9   9   9   10  10  10  10
          NaN   NaN 10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
          NaN   NaN NaN 10  10  9   10  10  10  9
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN 9   9   10  9   10  10
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN 9   10  10  10  10
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  11  10  10
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  10  10
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  10
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10
          NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

and I do this following :

```
C=size(minval,2);
D1(1,2:end) = minval(1,2:C);
D2 = bsxfun(@plus,minval(2:C-1,3:C),D1(1,1:C-2)');
D2 = [zeros(1,size(D2,2)) ;D2];
D2(D2==0) = NaN;
D1(2,3:end) = nanmin(D2);
D3 = bsxfun(@plus,minval(3:C-1,4:C),D1(2,2:C-2)');
D3 = [zeros(2,size(D3,2)) ;D3];
D3(D3==0) = NaN;
D1(3,4:end)= nanmin(D3);
```

Then, I want to  backtrack the path which `D1(end,end)`comes from.
Is there any help?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you can index out parts of matrices directly. There's no need for loops here:

```
C=size(minval,2);
D1(2:C) = minval(1,2:C);
```

For these ones you are not doing what you hoped, I suspect:

```
for e=3:C
  for b=2:e-1
    D2(e)=min(minval(b,e)+D1(b-1));
  end
end
```

In the inner loop, for each value of `b` (from 2 to e-1), you are overwriting the value of D2 at each step. Only the result for the last value of `b` will be recorded. There may well be a much simpler way of getting the result you want. `min` and other functions do not just work on two single values but on entire matrices - e.g. you can do:

```
min(minval)

ans =

   NaN     7     8     9     9     9    10     9    10     9
```

Comment: I've edited my question to resolve the overwriting issue. Thank you for your suggestion any way. Is there any help for the backtracking?